# Java LinkedList keep reference to nodes and add

Tags: java

I'm working with a `LinkedList` in Java where I, using one thread, add and remove items to the list. I only add elements at the head, since I'm using the list as a queue. I might add one element, remove it using the node, and add another element etc. Since it is double-linked it is obviously a possibility.

I should be able to keep a reference to the node, which is done through iterators in Java, however when I create an iterator and then add something to the linked list, and then remove the element through the iterator I previously created, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I've been scouring the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and can't find anything.

I do understand why I get the exception (it's stated in the docs...), however how do I achieve this using `LinkedList`? It's obviously possible.

**EDIT**:
People commenting might not understand how a double-linked list work, so let me run you through it shortly.

A double-linked list has a reference to it's previous and next element, hence you can **delete** it only referencing the node in O(1).

Next step, I'm clarifying what behavior I want:

1. Add an element to the list.
2. Save a **reference** `r` to that node.
3. Add another element.
4. Delete the old reference `r`.

**EDIT #2**:
I can add that C++ can do this with no problems (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html: Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a **different** thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception.

Comment: @misko321 Let me clarify.

Comment: Is there any reason you use an iterator instead of a variable? Usually iterators are needed when you want to traverse a list and have the option to delete or modify an element while traversing. See the docs for `ListIterator<E>` for that matter. If you just want to be able to delete a specific node after adding another one just store the object you want to remove in a variable and call `list.remove(objectToRemove)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018295/iterating-a-linkedlist

Comment: @FrankAndres If I use a variable I get O(n) deletion time, storing the node gives me O(1).

Comment: You could write your own implementation of a double linked list. The node class would store the previous and next node. The node itself would function as a container for your values. I'm pretty sure you can find plenty of examples on google on how to support all the operations of a double linked list when implementing it yourself. It should be possible to also implement the Interface List doing this. I don't think what you need is achievable with the standard library as it keeps the Nodes private.

Comment: Yes @FrankAndres, that is true. However I don't like reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: Yeah that's onviously a concern but I think there's no other option if you want to remove an element in O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible, and you should be using ConcurrentLinkedDeque.

JVM is sufficiently optimized that there won't be much of performance hit, and it advertises just that:

*Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the deque at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html

Comment: Well I guess using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` to support a faster deletion of elements kind of defeats the purpose if all that needs to be achieved is better performance in a single threaded environment as the `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` should be slower than a double linked list in most other operations.